Sum of cubes of characters in Representation Theory
Let $G$ be a finite group and consider $Irr(G)$, the set of the irreducible complex characters of $G$.
It is known that $\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \chi(g)$ is given by the number of square roots of $g\in G$. Also, as it can be checked here (Sum of squares of characters), $\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \chi^2(g)$ can tell us about the real elements of $G$ (an element $g\in G$ is said to be real if $g \thicksim g^{-1}$).
Are there any results about $\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \chi^3(g)$?

Don't you mean that $Irr(G)$ is just the set of irreducible complex characters of $G$? Because the space they generate is the space of all class functions (functions that are constant on conjugation classes), and like most vector spaces it has a tendency to be infinite.

@CaptainLama Sorry, I mean the set of irreducible complex characters of G. Thanks, I will edit it.

``It is known that $\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \chi(g)$ is given by the number of square roots of $g\in G$.'' What do you mean by that? If $G$ is abelian, then this sum is $0$ if $g\ne1$
